# Passing data between excel sheet and infopath 2010 form(web enabled)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath-data-connections

Hi I am using data connection(SOAP web service) to pass data between infopath form field and excel cells. I am following the below article - http://blogs.technet.com/b/jessmeats/archive/2009/12/01/infopath-and-excel-services.aspx

but i am getting an error when i hit the button which runs all the data connections - something like

```
workbook is cannot open because it is not stored in trusted location
```

I checked in central admin and the document library which holds the excel sheet does reside in trusted location.. any suggestions?